# Use jsdoc inline on argument in function

Tags: jsdoc

Currently I introduce an argument called `data` just so I can give it a type:

```
/**
 * @type {HomeOverview} data
 */
const data =  { id: homeId, name: home.name, notificationCnt };
sails.sockets.broadcast(userId, 'joined_home', data);
```

However I ideally just want to pass this inline like this pseudo-comment:

```
sails.sockets.broadcast(userId, 'joined_home', { id: homeId, name: home.name, notificationCnt }/*@type {HomeOverview}*/);
```

Is this pseudo-comment style valid?

Answer (score 0):

While ESLint will not throw any warnings or issues, Closure responds with a warning of:

```
 WARNING - Misplaced type annotation. Type annotations are not allowed here. Are you missing parentheses?
```